# Find the Laplace Transformation of $H(\pi-t)$.

Tags: laplace-transform

I know how to find the Laplace Transformation of $H(t-\pi)$, but what about if the $t$ is negative. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Heaviside function $H$ is defined as $1$ when its argument is positive and zero otherwise.  Thus, for $H(\pi-t)$, the function is $1$ when $t<\pi$ and $0$ otherwise. Thus,

$\int_0^{\infty}H(\pi-t)e^{-st}dt=\int_0^{\pi}e^{-st}dt=\frac1 s (1-e^{-\pi t})$

Thus, the result is identical to that from the sum $H(t)-H(t-\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the unilateral Laplace transform, you can see
that ${\cal L} (t \mapsto H(\pi-t)) = {\cal L} (1_{[0,\pi]})$. So you need to
compute the Laplace transform of a pulse of length $\pi$.

Similarly, you could note that
${\cal L} (t \mapsto H(\pi-t)) = {\cal L} (t \mapsto H(t)-H(t-\pi))$.